# Build 32-bit on 64-bit Ubuntu: installing ia32-libs does not include libstdc++

Tags: 64-bit, compiling, 32-bit

Googled for a while but drawn a blank.

Need to build 32-bit app on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Realise that I need to install ia32-libs. I have done this and apt-get tells me it's already at the latest version.

This link: http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/ia32-libs/filelist
says that libstdc++ should be in /usr/lib32

It's not there!

I have uninstalled, reinstalled (with force) ia32-libs.

Any ideas? How can I get this critter on my box?

Ta,
Ben

Comment: Try `dpkg -L ia32-libs`; this will show you where the files were installed.

Answer (score 10):

You need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Here are [more details on Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers).

Answer (score 9):

Try installing this:

`apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

It installs this:

```
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to build 32 bit apps on 64 bit system is using a 32 bit chroot. There are some excellent notes on how to do this in this wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot